# Turjs squareGrid doesn't render map

Tags: mapbox-gl, turfjs

I want to create 10 x 10 meter squares that cover the whole world. I'm using turfjs and mapboxgl. The map is rendering too late, giving an error.

Code:

```
  const bbox = [-175, -80, 175, 80];
  const cellSide = 10;
  const options = { units: "meters" };
  const squares = squareGrid(bbox, cellSide, options);

  map.on("load", function () {
     map.current.addSource("grid", {
       type: "geojson",
       data: squares,
     });
     map.current.addLayer({
       id: "grid",
       type: "line",
       source: "grid",
       minzoom: 9,
       paint: {
         "line-color": "red",
       },
     });
  });
```

Where am I doing wrong?